# Iterate over CURL POST payload in bash

Tags: json, bash, post, curl, payload

I have CURL POST batch command which I am planning to use in my script.I need to iterate over my json Payload as below:

The command for eg would  be like :

```
curl -v -X POST -d ‘{
  "parts": [
    {
      "id": "part1",
      "path": "/latest/inv",
      "operation": "create",
      "payload": {
        "item1": $item1,
        "item2": $item2,
        "item3": $item3,
        "item4": $item4,
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "part2",
      "path": "/latest/inv",
      "operation": "create",
      "payload": {
        "item1": $item1,
        "item2": $item2,
        "item3": $item3,
        "item4": $item4,
      }
    }
  ]
}' slcad988.us.oracle.com:10615/crmCommonApi/resources/latest -H "Content-Type:application/vnd.oracle.adf.batch+json" --user “user1"
```

I am writing a script that where I need to loop the payload entries such that I can keep appending the payload with "," comma separated till a count variable I have i.e say 10 it needs to generate 10 payloads i.e appending each payload entry generated
such that my final Payload will be of format :

```
"parts" : [
{
"id:part1",
....
},
{
"id:part2",
....
},
{
"id:part3",
....
},
...
{
"id:part10",
....
}
}}
```

How to acheive this kind of payload using bash. I was trying use EOF but did not have much luck.Any someone please help on how to achieve this scenario.Thanks in advance for the help.